# Does vampire lord paladin gain bonus to saves equal to twice his charisma modifier?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-advancement

**Divine Grace (Su)**

> At 2nd level, a paladin gains a bonus equal to her Charisma bonus (if
> any) on all saving throws.

[Vampire lord template](https://web.archive.org/web/20211115093505/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mm/20021018a)

> Same as the base vampire, plus the vampire lord applies its Charisma modifier to all saving throws in addition to its other ability modifiers (as a paladin does).

**Does it stack?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, it stacks

Let's review the stacking rules.

> In most cases, modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a cumulative effect) **if they come from different sources** and have different types (or no type at all), but do not stack if they have the same type or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast twice in succession)

Are two different abilities different sources? Yes. One is a source called Divine Grace. The other is not a named ability. Its descriptive text mentions that it works *like* a paladin ability, but they are not the same.

Comment: So this explains the trend to sparkly, sexy vampires. They're stacking Charisma.